# Change TIFF image projection without losing layers in QGIS 3.2?

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff

I have a .tif file (see color image below) that has 10 bandsets corresponding to a different color in the image. When I import the image to QGIS I can see all 10 layers. I need to reproject the image so it has units of degrees, not meters. I use  Raster -> Projections -> Warp (reproject) and then choose target CRS as EPSG:4326-WGS 84. However, when I run the program I get my reprojected image but I lost all of my layers. All I get is a binary image (see bw image below). How do I reproject my .tif  image so it maintains its color scheme and layers?

[image]

[image]